# windows phone 8.1 map moving speed

Tags: geolocation, position, windows-phone-8.1, maps

I'm trying to get the speed of movement but it doesn't work and I don't know why . here's what I tried

```
async private void locator_PositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            Geoposition geoPosition = e.Position;
            GeolocatorPositionChanged(geoPosition);

            var speed = e.Position.Coordinate.Speed; // en metres
            speed = speed * 3600 / 1000;
            speedTextBlock.Text = "speed : " + Convert.ToString(speed) ;
        });
    }
```

but coordinate.speed always return 5.8 (meters per sec)!

Comment: The speed is already in meters per second. What are you looking for (km/h?) Assuming 5.8m/s, you should be calculating about 20kmh/12mph which is certainly reasonable depending on the scenario.